# Setup SQL Server Reporting Services URL on Separate Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm a web developer, and my DBA is asking for help setting up SQL Server Reporting Services. He installed SSRS on the database server itself.

I've always been of the opinion that the web server portion of an application should be on separate server from the database. SSRS seems to want to set up the web access portion of SSRS on the same server (database server).

Is this acceptable practice to serve the SSRS reports directly over the web from the database server? I've searched for documentation on setting up the web site up on a separate web server and have not found any information.

Comment: There's another component here: the SSRS application server (i.e. the SSRS service that sits in services). You can easily install SSRS Web + App Server together on a different server to the database server. Are you saying you want to seperate the web components from the app server components  (the SSRS Service). I don't know if that's possible

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ok - I am asking if I can separate the web components from the app server. But maybe a better solution would be to install SSRS (application + web) components on a web server instead of the database server?

Comment: Yes definitely. If you want to split the load off, install the Web+App component on a different server (it's generally a good idea to have the database server standalone). I wouldn't bother trying to split the web server from the app server. I don't even know if you can do that. The only decision to make is: do you want to leave your SSRS system databases (2) on the original database server or move them to the web server also? It's generally simpler to leave them on the original database server.

Comment: So basically that means running the SQL Server install wizard on your web server and _only_ installing SSRS. Then configure it to use SSRS system databases on your original database server.

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable to have SSRS and SSDS on the same server, as long as the server has enough resources to handle the load. *Ideally*, they should be separated.

SSRS can grab a lot of RAM all of a sudden when someone deploys, and runs a poorly written report. If you think that could happen, separate them, sooner rather than later.